# linux x64: segmentation fault due to an argument value unreasonably changed when calling a function

Tags: function, arguments, 64-bit, coredump

an application frequently dumped cores due to segmentation fault, and its backtrace looks like below.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000039c6c71874 in strncpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000016fab83 in CcString::CcString (this=0x470008e0, str=...) at ../../base/src/ccString.cpp:163
#2  0x00000000016face9 in CcString::operator= (this=0x47000bf0, str=...) at ../../base/src/ccString.cpp:250
#3  0x0000000000441193 in RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(const CallPartyNumber_t *, ._2039, CcString &) (this=0x2af86a4de008, apNumber=0xb90160, aFormatType=NUMBER_FORMAT_TYPE_LDAP, aFormatedNumber=...) at ../main/RmsDbMgr.cpp:4465
#4  0x0000000000b1cacf in SessionMt::sendLdapQueryReq (this=0x2cb8d580, apNumber=0x2cb90160, aRecipient=true) at ../session/SessionMt.cpp:1600
```

in frame 4, apNumber=0x2cb90160, but in frame 3 its value was changed to 0xb90160 and that pointer caused segmentation fault later.

what could cause that happen? and why backtrace format of frame 3 doesn't look quite similar to other lines?

i tried a little bit with assembly ...

```
(gdb) disass sendLdapQueryReq
Dump of assembler code for function SessionMt::sendLdapQueryReq(CallPartyNumber_t const*, bool):
   0x0000000000b1ca40 <+0>:     mov    %rbp,-0x28(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca45 <+5>:     mov    %r15,-0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca4a <+10>:    mov    %rdi,%rbp
   0x0000000000b1ca4d <+13>:    mov    %rbx,-0x30(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca52 <+18>:    mov    %r12,-0x20(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca57 <+23>:    mov    %rsi,%r15
   0x0000000000b1ca5a <+26>:    mov    %r13,-0x18(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca5f <+31>:    mov    %r14,-0x10(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca64 <+36>:    sub    $0x208,%rsp
   0x0000000000b1ca6b <+43>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000b1ca74 <+52>:    mov    %rax,0x1c8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca7c <+60>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000b1ca7e <+62>:    mov    %dl,0x93(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca85 <+69>:    movl   $0x2,0x1c4(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1ca90 <+80>:    callq  0x1c2b406 <mxLog::GetInstance()>
   0x0000000000b1ca95 <+85>:    movzbl 0x8(%rax),%eax
   0x0000000000b1ca99 <+89>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000b1ca9b <+91>:    jne    0xb1cbb8 <SessionMt::sendLdapQueryReq(CallPartyNumber_t const*, bool)+376>
   0x0000000000b1caa1 <+97>:    lea    0x140(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000b1caa9 <+105>:   callq  0x16f7570 <CcString::CcString()>
   0x0000000000b1caae <+110>:   mov    0xc8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000b1cab5 <+117>:   lea    0x140(%rsp),%rcx
   0x0000000000b1cabd <+125>:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0x0000000000b1cabf <+127>:   mov    %r15,%rsi
   0x0000000000b1cac2 <+130>:   mov    0x28(%rax),%rax
   0x0000000000b1cac6 <+134>:   mov    0x58(%rax),%rdi
   0x0000000000b1caca <+138>:   callq  0x441110 <RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(const CallPartyNumber_t *, ._2039, CcString &)>
=> 0x0000000000b1cacf <+143>:   cmpq   $0x0,0x150(%rsp)
   0x0000000000b1cad8 <+152>:   je     0xb1cb88 <SessionMt::sendLdapQueryReq(CallPartyNumber_t const*, bool)+328>
   0x0000000000b1cade <+158>:   movl   $0x2,0x1c4(%rsp)
```

before calling RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(), %rsi (2nd argument considering THIS as first) was set as %r15 which was 0x2cb90160, that was correct.

```
(gdb) p/x $r15
$9 = 0x2cb90160
```

and assembly of RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber() as below ...

```
(gdb) disass getFormatedNumber
Dump of assembler code for function RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(const CallPartyNumber_t *, ._2039, CcString &):
   0x0000000000441110 <+0>:     mov    %rbp,-0x28(%rsp)
   0x0000000000441115 <+5>:     mov    %r13,-0x18(%rsp)
   0x000000000044111a <+10>:    mov    %edx,%ebp
   0x000000000044111c <+12>:    mov    %r14,-0x10(%rsp)
   0x0000000000441121 <+17>:    mov    %r15,-0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000441126 <+22>:    mov    %rdi,%r14
   0x0000000000441129 <+25>:    mov    %rbx,-0x30(%rsp)
   0x000000000044112e <+30>:    mov    %r12,-0x20(%rsp)
   0x0000000000441133 <+35>:    sub    $0x178,%rsp
   0x000000000044113a <+42>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000441143 <+51>:    mov    %rax,0x138(%rsp)
   0x000000000044114b <+59>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000044114d <+61>:    test   %rsi,%rsi
   0x0000000000441150 <+64>:    mov    %rsi,%r13
   0x0000000000441153 <+67>:    mov    %rcx,%r15
   0x0000000000441156 <+70>:    je     0x4411e0 <RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(const CallPartyNumber_t *, ._2039, CcString &)+208>
   0x000000000044115c <+76>:    cmp    $0x2,%edx
   0x000000000044115f <+79>:    jg     0x4411e0 <RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(const CallPartyNumber_t *, ._2039, CcString &)+208>
   0x0000000000441165 <+85>:    lea    0x100(%rsp),%rdi
   0x000000000044116d <+93>:    callq  0x16f7570 <CcString::CcString()>
   0x0000000000441172 <+98>:    movzwl 0x53e74(%r14),%esi
   0x000000000044117a <+106>:   lea    0x100(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000441182 <+114>:   callq  0x16f90e0 <CcString::operator+=(u16_t const)>
   0x0000000000441187 <+119>:   lea    0x8(%r13),%rsi
   0x000000000044118b <+123>:   mov    %r15,%rdi
   0x000000000044118e <+126>:   callq  0x16facc0 <CcString::operator=(CcString const&)>
=> 0x0000000000441193 <+131>:   movl   $0x2,0x134(%rsp)
   0x000000000044119e <+142>:   callq  0x1c2b406 <mxLog::GetInstance()>
   0x00000000004411a3 <+147>:   movzbl 0x8(%rax),%eax
   0x00000000004411a7 <+151>:   test   %al,%al
```

in RmsDbMgr::getFormatedNumber(), %r15 was saved at -0x8(%rsp) before sp moving up 0x178 bytes, and it was 0x2cb90160 too.

```
(gdb) x/a $rsp+0x178-0x8
0x47000aa0:     0x2cb90160
```

then before doing anything, %rsi was assigned to %r13, but now r13 had a different value which wrong.

```
(gdb) p/x $r13
$9 = 0xb90160
```

anyone can help to find out what's wrong with it?

Comment: One common cause of this sort of problems is `strncpy` overwriting some program data. Double check the pointer and length parameters passed to it. Also check for range overlap (between [src, src + len) and [dst, dst + len)).

Comment: %r15 and %r13 are caller registers, not in memory. also from frame 2, it's accessing incorrect memory pointer 0xb90160 which i think caused the segmentation fault

Comment: and also it didn't crash after i compiled application with -fstack-protector option. but as i understand -fstack-protector should intentionally crash the application in case of stack overflow if there's problem in my code causing that trouble.